# Playing a random sound but not the same twice in a row loop

Tags: python, random

is it possible to play a sound like 1, 2, 3 or 4. While not playing the same twice in a row, but it can still be in the overall pool?
The `random.choice` will be continue in a loop, but can pick the same twice in a row.
But I can't seem to make the `random.shuffle` go in a loop?

```
while True: 
    sounds = ["test1.mp3", "test2.mp3", "test3.mp3", "test4.mp3",]
    play = random.shuffle(sounds)
    playsound(play)
```

Comment: Just store which ones you've used in an array and check against it in your while loop.

Comment: Store the generated play in a list and while generating next item, just check it whether it exists in played list or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick a random sound from the list, excluding the last one.  Then move the sound that you picked at the last position in the list.

```
import random
sounds = ["test1.mp3", "test2.mp3", "test3.mp3", "test4.mp3"]
while True:
    i = random.randrange(len(sounds)-1)  # pick before last
    sounds.append(sounds.pop(i))         # move it to end
    print(sounds[-1])                    # play selected
    
test1.mp3
test4.mp3
test3.mp3
test4.mp3
test1.mp3
test3.mp3
test4.mp3
test2.mp3
test1.mp3
test2.mp3
test4.mp3
...
```

This will ensure that you never have the same sound twice in a row.

You can improve on this by only selecting sounds from the first half of the list.  Then a given sound will never be repeated within half the total number of sounds.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to make a if statement that check if the previous number = the current item. To do this you need to add this.

```
if play != previous:
    playsound(play)
    previous = play
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a song to play, remove the last song from the list.

```py
import time
import random
random.seed(0)


def playsound(sound: str):
    """Define your function instead of printing these."""
    print("start: " + sound)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(sound + " ended")


sounds = ["test1.mp3", "test2.mp3", "test3.mp3", "test4.mp3"]
prev = None  # the last played song
while True:
    nominees = sounds.copy()
    if prev is not None:
        nominees.remove(prev)

    prev = random.choice(nominees)
    playsound(prev)
```